# How to make Weka API work with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, weka

I'm looking to use WEKA to train and predict from data in MongoDB. Specifically, I intend to use Weka API to analyse data (e.g. build a recommendation engine). But I have no idea how to proceed, because the data in MongoDB is stored in the BSON format, while WEKA uses the ARFF format. I would like to use the WEKA API to read data from MongoDB, analyse it, and provide recommendations to the user in real-time. I can not find a bridge beween WEKA and MongoDB.

Is this even possible or should I try another approach?

Comment: This link shows a good example of defining your own .arff file programatically.  https://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use

Comment: Have you considered using a mongodb jdbc or odbc driver to access MongoDB data from weka?

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin, I should say that WEKA isn't the best tool for working with Big Data. If you really have Big Data, you will likely want to use [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) and the Hadoop family as they are more suited to analysis.

To answer your question as written, I would advise doing the training manually (i.e. creating a training file using any programmatic tools available to you) and pretraining a model. These models can then be saved and integrated into a program accordingly.

For testing, you can follow the [official instructions](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use), but I usually take a bit of a shortcut: I usually preprocess my data into a CSV-like format (as if it was going into an ARFF file) and just prepend a valid ARFF header (the same one as your training file uses). From there, it is very easy to test the instances. In my experience, this greatly simplifies the process of writing code that actually makes novel predictions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I thought about using Weka like your idea. But I will try to study Spark! If it is better choice, I will take it into my project!
Many thanks! :)